# Validations on dynamically added table rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, rows, dynamically-generated

I am working on a form which adds dynamic table rows to the table I have done some validations for it which works fine for me, but now I am facing a new challenge that I want to validate a text box which will be added  dynamically on every row, but the problem is I just want to validate that textbox when the other textboxs which comes before it are not empty
and I am stuck here. I know I can use `.each()` for every element that comes into that id, but I don't know how do I bind every textbox from the row in that validation, because the rows will itself add up when the last textbox("which I need to validate") is not empty, and if all textboxes are not empty then it wont give any error.

Here is my code for validation:

```
if($('[id^="invoice_"]').val() =="" || $('[id^="invoice_"]').val() ==null || $('[id^="invoice_"]').val() ==0){
     alert("Invoice Number Cannot Be Empty");
     $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     console.log("1");
     return false;
}else{
  console.log("2");
     $("#savetodb").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

well you don't need to add selector for each input ... try using loop

```
 $.each($('[id^="invoice_"]'),function(i,v){
   if(this.value=="" || this.value==null || this.value=="0"){
      alert("Invoice Number Cannot Be Empty");
      $("#savetodb").prop("disabled", true);
      console.log("1");
      return false;
   }else{
      console.log("2");
       $("#savetodb").prop("disabled", false);
   }
```

and yes this has to be inside your submit function and should be called after all your input is added. recommned to use `prop()` if you have latest version of jquery used (i.e 1.6+)

Comment: thanks for the answer but will it work for me like i want to validate the ("invoice_number") when every textbox on that row is not empty
for example :
  if(this.value=="" || this.value==null || this.value=="0" && $("#textbox1").val() !="" &&$("#textbox2").val() !="" &&$("#textbox3").val() !="")

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
May be it will help to you...

Code side (.cs page) :

```
        string str = "";
        str = "<table>";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            str = str + "<tr><Label id='lbl" + i.ToString() + "' runat='server'>Lable " + i.ToString() + "</Label>";
            str = str + "<input type='Text' id='txt" + i.ToString() + "' onblur='checkValidation(this);'/></tr><br /><br />";
        }
        str = str + "</table>";
        Response.Write(str);
```

Design Side (.aspx page) :

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function checkValidation(ctrl) {
            var returnNow = false;
            var i = 0;
            $('input[type=text]').each(function (index) {
                if (ctrl.id == this.id) {
                    if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == null) {
                        alert('enter some val for Label ' + (index + 1).toString());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == null) {
                        alert('Enter some value for Label ' + (index + 1).toString());
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        returnNow = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```